# Top bar and footer don't fill width when browser is horizontally scrollable

Tags: bug

I've been reviewing whilst semi-watching videos on my laptop so I don't quite have the full 1000 or so pixels of width free to fit StackOverflow in all its glory. The page scrolls horizontally and I end up scrolling back and forth left to right to hit the various action buttons.

Currently the top bar and the footer are set to 100% width, so as soon as you scroll to the right, the black background stops despite the content continuing. As shown here:

[image: Exhibits A and B]

Obviously this is purely cosmetic, but in Web Inspector it can be fixed by simply setting a `min-width` on the `<div class="topbar">` and `<div id="footer" class="container">` elements. I know very little about css and cross browser compatibility so there may be more to it but to an untrained eye it appears trivial.

Reproduced in Safari 7, FireFox 26, Chrome 32 - Mac OS X Mavericks.

Almost certainly a duplicate, can't find it myself though.

Comment: curse you magic sidebar

Comment: 3D drop-shadow freehand lines deserve a honourable upvote in any case.

Comment: Haha thank you kindly